# Changing variable inside block

Tags: objective-c

I have this defined at top of a method:

`__block BOOL flag;`

I have a UIView animation block, and inside it I have this:

```
flag=YES;
NSLog(@"the value of the flag is %i",flag);
```

However, instead of returning 1, it logs as 0.

Other things in the block are running correctly. What could be happening here?

Comment: (What is `__block`? :-/)

Comment: objective-c  blocks are like one-off functions; the `__block` means you are giving a block function control over setting this variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have any method accidentally set `flag = NO;`? Because it looks like everything is fine. I even tried it by myself and I can get it logged as 1.(Same code you used)

Comment: I did actually, and discovered that right after I posted the question. Thanks for the help!